# SceneManager.LoadScene() Freezes for a Short Time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a very small game with Unity 5.5. The first scene is a menu scene. Menu scene consists of just 2 buttons and 2 images but takes 3 4 seconds to load which is too much. Then I change to the Game Scene, which has 3 objects including camera and SceneManager.LoadScene() freezes again for about 2 seconds. My image sizes are decent and I can't figure out the reason for this. I have examined games made with unity and thay definetely use larger graphics and don't have this problem. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your loading script please.

Comment: Also, what the image sizes?

Comment: There are several things that can be causing it, let's start with seeing how you are loading script, then start by showing us you images you are loading their sizes, and your compression settings.

Comment: Use LoadSceneAsync so you can display a loading bar. Or LoadAdditive so it loads on the back.

Comment: Problem is solved. It was that the graphics provider gave us very large images where we didn't need. And we just couldn't realize that few images that caused the problem. Also loading the scene asynchronously helps improve the player experience. Thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply:)